# CImg failed to recognize the format "jpeg"

Tags: xcode, imagemagick, cimg

To load image, I installed the CImg library in my mac(OSX 10.10). Luckily I managed to display the bmp picture, but I failed to load and display other formats like png or jpg.
Then I installed the ImageMagic which is downloaded from http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/ and then run the program. The errors are still there.

My code is :

```
#include "CImg.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#define cimg_use_magick
using namespace cimg_library;

int main() {
CImg<unsigned char> image("lena.jpg");

image.display();

return 0;
}
```

The program can be built successfully in my Xcode but it reported the error that is "failed to recognize the format"
I just don't know how to fix it. thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do - I mean what is your ultimate goal? I'm not being funny - I just suspect you may be on the wrong track - or let's say there may be better tracks you could be on.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I just want to use cimg to load images for my OpenGL program. Since I can't figure it out, I turn to SDL2_image

Comment: Just noticed... you need to do `#define cimg_use_magick` **before** `#include "CImg.h"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing your ImageMagick installation does not have the necessary libraries for reading JPEG files. ImageMagick refers to the handlers for the various image formats as `DELEGATES`, so try this command to see what formats your ImageMagick installation can cope with:

```
identify -list configure | grep DELEGATES
DELEGATES      bzlib mpeg freetype jng jpeg lzma png tiff xml zlib
```

Personally, I never had any success with the `CactusLabs` installation. I use `homebrew`. You copy the one-liner installation script from [here](http://brew.sh), and then you can simply manage all packages on your Mac with the `brew` command. For example, to find the name of the ImageMagick package, just do

```
brew search imagemagick
```

To install ImageMagick, run

```
brew install imagemagick
```

To uninstall ImageMagick, run

```
brew rm imagemagick
```

To install Cimg, run

```
brew install cimg
```

To find `ffmpeg`, or `GNU Parallel`, just do

```
brew search ffmpeg
brew search parallel
```

To sort out any problems with `homebrew`, just call the Doctor:

```
brew doctor
```

and it will tell you about any problems or inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It really seems that my mac lacks the some neccessary libraries.

Comment: You can do `brew install libjpg libpng libtiff`